# Highchart dynamically change the xAxis type

Tags: highcharts

Highchart, dynamically change the xAxis type.now,xAxis type "logarithmic" is change "linear" ,there is an error occurred "uncaught exception: Highcharts error #10: www.highcharts.com/errors/10"?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check www.highcharts.com/errors/10?  It says:
Highcharts Error #10

Can't plot zero or subzero values on a logarithmic axis

This error occurs in the following situations:
If a zero or subzero data value is added to a logarithmic axis
If the minimum of a logarithimic axis is set to 0 or less
If the threshold is set to 0 or less